# Initialize neural network weights with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

I am developing a neural network model using Tensorflow. In the LOSO cross validation, I need to train a model for 10 folds, since I have data from 10 different subjects.

Taking this into account, I need to reset the optimizer and the network weights at the start of every cross-validation fold. I defined the weights as follows:

```
weights = {
    'w1' : tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape = [100, 10],seed =   0)),

    'w2' : tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape = [10, 100],seed = 0))}
```

and I reset the Optimizer and the weights by reinitializing all global variables as follows:

```
# Start session to run Tensors and Operations
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)
    # Variables initializer
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    # Loop over the 10 cross-validation subjects
    for subject in range(0,10):
        # Initialize global variables and optimizer
        sess.run(init)
        # Print initialized weights (should be always the same)
        print(sess.run(weights['w1']))
        # Loop over epochs to train the model
        for epoch in range(epochs):         
            # Run network optimizer for the current epoch
            _,cost = sess.run([optimizer,loss], feed_dict ={X:x_train[subject,:], Y:y_train[subject,:]})
```

However, in every iteration of the loop I get printed different values for the weights, like the Operation seed I set to 0 is not doing its job. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: How can you expect the same weights if the input variables change at each fold?.

Comment: Because the weights are printed at the beginning of the fold, before any input is passed to the optimizer @Neb

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what's happening is the following. Suppose you set the initial seed at 42, at the beginning of your script:

```
set_seed(42)
```

Then, you sample a random number:

```
sample()
>>> 0.875
```

Now, you sample again:

```
sample()
>>> 0.311
```

It is different. It's not a bug. The `set_seed()` function tells the system to sample "random" number starting from position 42 (in the sequence of pseudorandom numbers) **every time you run your program**, not every time the `sample` function is called. Try to run your program multiple times. You'll see that the weights of your parameters will be different between folds, but will be the same throughout multiple runs, i.e. in all runs, at fold 1, weights will be always initialized to the same value.

---

#### Now, how to solve this?

Sample a random initialization once, at the beginning of the script and initialize your weight with it at the beginning of each fold:

```
w = tf.Variable(..., initializer=YOUR_NUMPY_ARRAY)
```